# Ansible: capturing the failure msg and use it in the recover part of a block

Tags: ansible

I would like to find a way to capture the `msg` that is being logged to stdout when running `ansible-playbook`.

I know that I can just register the result of a task and use that as a variable, but I am including different roles with include_role and I'm struggling trying to find a way to just capture the error message.

Is there any smart way to do it?

As an example, let's pretend I have a playbook that looks like this:

```
- hosts: k8s-cluster:etcd:calico-rr
  any_errors_fatal: "{{ any_errors_fatal | default(true) }}"
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    roles:
      - name: "kubespray-defaults"
        tags: ""
      - name: "bootstrap-os"
        tags: "bootstrap-os"
      - name: "my-notification"
        tags: ""
        msg: kubespray-defaults and bootstrap-os completed
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

  tasks:
  - include_tasks: my_include_role.yml
    loop: "{{ roles }}"
```

And here's my_include_role.yml

```
- name: my-include-role
  block:
    - include_role:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        apply:
          tags: >-
            {%- if item.tags is defined -%}
            "{{ item.tags }}"
            {%- else -%}
            []
            {%- endif -%}

      vars:
        msg: "{% if item.msg is defined %}{{ item.msg }}{% endif %}"
        host: "{% if item.host is defined %}{{ item.host }}{% endif %}"
        result: "{% if item.result is defined %}{{ item.result }}{% endif %}"
        error: false
  rescue:
    - debug:
        msg: "before notification"
    - include_role:
        name: "my-notification"
      vars:
        msg: an error has occurred
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        result: "{% if action_result is defined %}{{ action_result.msg }}{% endif %}"
        role: "{{ item.name }}"
        error: true
    - debug:
        msg: "after notification"
  always:
    - debug:
        msg: "include completed"
```

And my-notification is the following:

```
---
- name: report an event
  delegate_to: localhost
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost:8090/"
    method: GET
    body_format: json
    body: "{\"time\":\"{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro }}\", \"pod_id\":\"{{ pod_id }}\", \"msg\":\"{{ msg }}\", \"host\":\"{{ host }}\"{% if role is defined%}, \"role\":\"{{ role }}\"{% endif %}{% if result is defined%}, \"result\":\"{{ result }}\"{% endif %}{% if error is defined%}, \"error\":{{ error }}{% endif %}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"I'm struggling trying to find a way to just capture the error message."*

A: It's possible to use [Playbook Debugger](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_debugger.html#playbook-debugger).

> *"You can then, for example, check or set the value of variables, update module arguments, and re-run the task with the new variables and arguments to help resolve the cause of the failure."*

For example

```
- name: Play
  hosts: all
  debugger: on_failed
  tasks:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, I didn't know about the debugger. But do you also know ho to turn the error message that is being printed to stdout by ansible-playbook into a variable that can be passed to the task doing the recovery?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out by printing the task vars that what I need is `ansible_failed_result`. Thanks!

Comment: Right. It's a good idea to put critical sections into the [blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html?highlight=ansible_failed_result#blocks-error-handling). You're welcome!